# Can I use the construction like "get + gerund" (example: get moving) with continuous and perfect forms?

Tags: gerunds, perfect-constructions, continuous

I guess, I understand about usage of "get moving" or "get doing" in simple.

> I always get reading a new book as soon as I have free time.

What about continuous or perfect forms? Is it possible?

Comment: I'd say your cited usage is a fairly uncommon alternative to *I always **set about / start** reading a new book as soon as...* (or ***...start to read...***). But I can't see any good reason for using *any* of those rather than straightforward *I always **read** a new book as soon as...*

Comment: **Get ___ing** is often used like an imperative (*Get going!* or *Well, we need to get moving*) but it isn't used as a general replacement for "begin".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am confused. I asked the same question on another site and I got that: "Here are some common expressions using 'get going' with example sentences in present continuous, present perfect, and past perfect tenses:
**Present Continuous:** _He's getting going on his new project at work._
**Present Perfect:** _They have finally gotten going on their home renovation project._
**Past Perfect:** _By the time we arrived, they had already gotten going on the party preparations._" Then I asked, whether the examples were common, and I got answer "Yes"

Comment: All those examples are for ***[get / getting / gotten] going***, which is primarily an AmE rather than BrE usage anyway, but the main point is *He's **getting going** on his new project at work* is reasonably idiomatic everywhere, but *He's **getting reading** his new book* is *never* acceptable. And *I'll **get reading** this book when I have time* is "awkward", so you should avoid it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. So, does it partly depend on a verb that is used after "get"?

Comment: Well, it's true we native speakers do say you gotta [***get while the getting's good***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+while+the+getting%27s+good%22), but I'd advise you to steer clear of complex phrasal verb constructions involving ***to get*** wherever possible. Just say "I always **read** a new book as soon as I have free time." ([Geddit?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/geddit) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great, I appreciate the way you explained that to me! Thanks